# How to force excel to stop thinking your cell contains a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to enter, "-0.0028 (204)" into a cell in excel, but it keeps attempting to evaluate this (non-)expression as, "=-0.0028*(204)". This occurs even when I set the cell format to, "General". Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the single quote `'` before whatever you're entering.

Answer (score 5):

Format the cell as **Text**

or

precede it with an apostrophe

or

enter it as a formula:

```
="-0.0028 (204)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter an apostrophe at the beginning of the cell

> '-0.0028*(204)